# Units of a vision

Tags: units

I have a basic question about physical units.
Say I have the following value:

a= $\frac{m1}{m2·g}$

m1,m2 being masses and g being gravitational acceleration. What would the units of this value be?

Is it $\frac{sec^2}{m}$, or $\frac{kg·sec^2}{m}$?

Comment: Why would you think of the second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mass units cancel leaving 1/g or seconds-squared over meters as you said. If a in your initial equation stands for acceleration then your equation is wrong. Your equation reduces to the units of 1/acceleration.

Comment: This is my opinion, you should never give direct answers to questions like these because that doesn't do anything to discourage questions like these on the website. A hint is always better (in some cases, atleast), it makes the questioner think for themselves as well.

Comment: Good point. I agree and apologize.  I'm fairly new to this. Should I delete my answer? I don't mind doing that either.

Comment: No that's alright, seeing it's accepted and all already. But be sure to keep that in mind in the future, though! (It helps maintain a standard for questions, which is healthy for the website)

Comment: Hritik, you're an arrogant asshole. Sorry my question was not up to your high standards.